# Does this construct Platonic solids?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

Consider $\mathrm{O}(3)\curvearrowright\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $\Gamma\subseteq\mathrm{O}(3)$ be a finite group. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ be a point such that $\mathrm{Stab}_\Gamma(x)$ has maximal size among $\Gamma$-stabilisers of $x'\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$. Then consider the convex hull of the orbit $\mathrm{CH}(\Gamma.x)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Assume that $\Gamma\curvearrowright\mathbb{R}^3$ has no proper invariant subspace. This excludes the factorization $\Gamma\subseteq\mathrm{O}(2)\subseteq\mathrm{O}(3)$.

Questions:

1. Is $\mathrm{CH}(\Gamma.x)$ a Platonic polytope? Can we recover every Platonic polytope up to dual?
2. For higher dimension $\mathrm{O}(n)\curvearrowright\mathbb{R}^n$, does this type of construction recover all regular polytopes up to dual?

Comment: I think you want the stabilizer to be a maximal subgroup, not a subgroup of maximal size. For example, the symmetry group of the cube has 48 elements, and the stabilizer of a vertex only has size 6, where as the stabilizer of the normal to a vertex has size 8. Same issue for the dodecahedron (6 for a vertex; 10 for the normal to a face).

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Good point. My guess would be that, if we start from the cube, and consider its symmetry, and construct a polytope as the post indicates, then we get a octaheron, which is dual to the cube. Therefore I guess the result is up to dual.

Comment: I think the subgroup of maximal size is the better formulation. Taking as $x$ the midpoint of a face just yields the dual of the original solid and the question is only up to dual.
On the other hand, if we allow any maximal subgroup, we could also take the stabilizer of a midpoint of an edge of a cube. This stabilizer is Z/2 x Z/2 and if I am not wrong, it is also maximal. The solid would then be a Cuboctahedron, which is not a platonic solid.

Comment: For Question 1: there are only very few irreducible [point groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions) in dimension three, so you could check one by one. Also, to find "all Platonic solids up to duality" you only need to find three. The respective symmetry groups of tetrahedron, octahedron and icosahedron should do the trick. They are also known as the reflection groups $A_3$, $B_3$ and $H_3$.